# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, centos, replicate

I´ve seen this question in another post, but I have one diference:

I´m triyng  to follow the instructions in https://www.telepieza.com/wordpress/2008/03/13/replicar-bases-de-datos-mysql-en-servidores-locales-o-remotos/

But my in my server originally the line: `#log-bin=mysql-bin` is commented (#)

If I let the line without the # and restarts the MySql the service doesn´t start and shows the error:

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/xxxxxx.pid).
```

Thanks for your help

*-----------------*
Added for the coments:

[image]
[2017 Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DP7s.png)

Comment: The error is just telling you it couldn't start mysqld. You should read the MySQL error log to get more specific information about *why* it failed to start. Your MySQL error log is probably in `/var/lib/mysqld.err` or `/var/lib/<hostname>.err`, but this can vary.

Comment: This is the error log

141023 12:39:48 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

141023 12:39:48 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/sd-941934-l.dattaweb.com.pid ended

141023 15:39:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

141023 15:39:10 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

141023 15:39:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

141023 15:39:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins

Comment: Those timestamps are from 2014-10-23. Is that what your server's system clock is set to? Are you looking at the right error log file?

Comment: That´s the only .err I found...

I add a image description of the ftp folder in the post above. Notice that the .pid has the 28/08/2017 update

Comment: Well I see the .pid file has a timestamp for the current date 2017-08-28, so that's an old error log file, not relevant to today's troubleshooting. You must have another .err log file somewhere else on your server. For example, on CentOS it's sometimes in /var/log/mysqld.log or /var/log/mysql/mysql.log. The location might be defined custom in /etc/my.cnf.

Comment: You´re Right...sorry.... I´ve posted the 2017 log in the post above.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error log, I see the error that it can't find the binary log file it expects to find. So some or all of your binary log files expired or got deleted or something. But there's still some reference to mysql-bin.000019 in mysql-bin.index.

I checked your screenshot you had posted previously and I see your mysql-bin.index is dated 2017-05-18. So it's three months out of date anyway. I would guess someone deleted the old binary logs to save space, but didn't think to delete the binlog index file.

If you want to start over with a clean slate of binary log files, just remove all your mysql-bin.* files (including mysql-bin.index), and then start mysqld. The startup will automatically create new binary logs, starting with mysql-bin.000001.

Note that if you have any replication slaves depending on this instance as their master, you'll have to reinitialize them with a new backup and the new binlog filename.